# Like Operator for checking multiple words

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I'm struggling for a `like` operator which works for below example

Words could be

```
MS004 -- GTER   
MS006 -- ATLT   
MS009 -- STRR   
MS014 -- GTEE   
MS015 -- ATLT
```

What would be the like operator in `Sql Server` for pulling data which will contain words like `ms004 and ATLT` or any other combination like above.

I tried using multiple like for example

```
where column like '%ms004 | atl%'
```

but it didn't work.

**EDIT**

Result should be combination of both words only.

Comment: Not an _exact_ duplicate, [but the solution to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612858/sql-server-2008-multiple-like-problem) should work for you too (or something similar).  There probably is a duplicate question somewhere around here...[this one is close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643409/how-to-use-like-statement-in-sql-plus-with-multiple-wild-carded-values) but terribly written/answered.

Comment: Do you store the GTER, ALTR in another column? What do you mean by combination exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this.

```
`where column like '%ms004%' or column like '%atl%'`
```

or this

```
`where column like '%ms004%atl%'
```

Comment: it won't work i tried it. It will get data which will cotnaining word `ms004` or `atl`. But it should be combination of both words actually...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
select .....from table where columnname like '%ms004%' or columnname like '%atl%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH LikeCond1 as (
SELECT 'MS004' as L1 UNION
SELECT 'MS006' UNION
SELECT 'MS009' UNION
SELECT 'MS014' UNION
SELECT 'MS015')
, LikeCond2 as (
SELECT  'GTER' as L2 UNION
SELECT 'ATLT' UNION
SELECT 'STRR' UNION
SELECT 'GTEE' UNION
SELECT 'ATLT'
)

SELECT TableName.*
FROM LikeCond1
    CROSS JOIN LikeCond2
    INNER JOIN TableName ON TableName.Column like '%' + LikeCond1.L1 + '%'
                        AND TableName.Column like '%' + LikeCond2.L2 + '%'
```